# Beamer: How to deemphasize some text / part of a slide in a theme friendly way?

Tags: beamer, emphasis

Is there a counterpart of the \emph command, namely one that de-emphasizes some text?  There is obviously the possibility to explicitly change the color to greyed-out, but that would depend on the theme / look bad with a different theme (i.e. a different background color).

Answer (score 2):

You could use beamer's `colormixin` environment to tune down parts of the text by mixing the foreground and background components of the current beamer colour.

If you use the same colour as the frame background for the background of the text font, this will make the text appear to blend in with the background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=green}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}

\setbeamercolor{normal font}{parent=background canvas}
\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamercolor{normal font}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
  \begin{colormixin}{20!bg}abc\end{colormixin}
  abc
  
  \begin{block}{}
    abc
    \begin{colormixin}{20!bg}abc\end{colormixin}
    abc
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(As my search on the web had not brought any usable results and since I had to investigate a bit to finally figure it out, I decided to share my findings and post the question and also the answer that I have found.)

There is an older discussion on [latex.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17731), where the OP requested (unsucessfully) for an explanation for using the style used in a table of contents for the shaded toc entries.  Based on that idea I figured out how to do it: There is a beamer color named `section in toc shaded`, which can be selected in the following way:

```
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in toc shaded}Your shaded text}
```

The color name is described in section "10.2 Adding Sections and Subsections" of the beamer manual, and the way to use beamer colors is explained in section "17.2.2 Using Beamer’s Colors".